# http to https htaccess redirect loop error

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I have a site which I am trying to completely redirect from `http` to `https`.

I need to redirect any user that arrives at the site via `http` to the same page on `https`.

The site is hosted on a provider's shared hosting. Since the domain's SSL certificate was installed, a new IP address has been assigned to the domain.

I have been advised that the following code should be added to my `.htaccess` file. There are also some rules which handle SEO friendly URLS.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# enforce https and www
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]

# skip further rules for files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# internal rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ page.php?venue=$1&artist=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ page.php?venue=$1 [L,QSA]
```

For some reason, the addition of this code to the `.htaccess` file, results in a redirection loop error. I have tried variants of the `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443` line as advised on other Stack Overflow posts, but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: As a side note, it may be to good to add the header "Strict-Transport-Security" that would get the redirection at the browser itself [assuming the browser supports this]

Comment: Can you show `VistualHost` entry of SSL site from Apache config.

Comment: I will see if I can get this information from the service provider. They advise me that the problem is not down to DNS. @anubhava Thanks once again for your help

Comment: Yes but DNS entry is different and `VirtualHost` setup is different.

Comment: I have found a statement from another provider and I wondered if this was the problem. http://www.networksolutions.com/support/ssl-redirects/

Comment: Hi @anubhava would any of the variables in the PHP solution that I have posted be able to be incorporated into a new htaccess condition?

Comment: Posted an answer below for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have been given this code from my service provider which seems to do the trick using php

```
<?php 
 if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL'] == '1') {  } else {    $redirect = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];    header("Location: $redirect"); } ?>
```

I can add the following for permanent redirection

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# enforce https and www
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]

# skip further rules for files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# internal rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ page.php?venue=$1&artist=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ page.php?venue=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Still no luck I'm afraid. I tried taking out the `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443 [OR]` to see if it made any difference but it would then not forward without the www. Looks like my php solution doesn't work cross browser either

Comment: If you test these rules it will also work. Doing the rewrite in PHP is not really a solution since it slows down your site considerably under high load.

Comment: Suppose you're right, it's a work around, not a solution to the htaccess problem. I will try again with your code and have a fiddle to see if i can get it to work

Comment: I have tried your code with a slight alteration and it works to forward `http://example.com` urls to `https://www.example.com`. I have removed `[OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443 [OR]` The only problem is, it does not forward `http://www.example.com` urls

Comment: Sorry, no luck. I think i have issues with `%{HTTPS} !on` and `%{SERVER_PORT} !=443` If that's in there, then it redirects infinitely.

Comment: Even I thought that one should have worked! No luck though I'm afraid

Comment: I suspect now that you're either not running Apache or running some broken version of it.

Comment: I have done a check and it is Apache, but it must be a virtualhost or whatever its called as I'm on shared hosting. I might have to stick with that php script I guess

Comment: But `RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]` rule is not dependent on any `VirtualHost`. Are you sure you don't have any other rule?

Comment: htaccess has `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` in it on line 1 and that is all.

Comment: Comment out `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]` line and see if you get redirection loop or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59704/discussion-between-anubhava-and-user2524219).