# http to https forwarding using php

Tags: php, https, http-status-code-301, forwarding

I have recently set up SSL on a domain. This is on shared hosting which seems to be causing problems with redirecting the site to `https`. I have asked previous [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316295/http-to-https-htaccess-redirect-loop-error) regarding this problem without success. Any attempt seems to result in the site entering an infinite redirect loop. I have been given the following code by the service provide who host the site, which solve the problem of redirection, but not across all browsers. On Chrome, the code works as intended forwarding a `http` page to its `https` counterpart. However tests in Internet Explorer seem to forward all pages to the `https` homepage and Firefox seems to just show an error screen. The code is as follows

```
 <?php 
 if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL'] == '1') {      header("Location: $redirect");    } else {    $redirect = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];    header("Location: $redirect"); } ?>
```

Could anyone elaborate on this code to find a solution to this now long running problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell why its not working but try the code below to redirect http:// to https://

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == ""){
    $redirect = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location: $redirect");
}
```

This will work on every browser.Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for you're prompt response. Unfortunately this code creates the same redirection loop problem. So I'm leaning more to a problem with the site being on shared hosting.

Comment: This page is not forwarding properly. It's the same error as a previous question I have asked regarding htaccess. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316295/http-to-https-htaccess-redirect-loop-error

Comment: OK bro one thing can be that you have not deleted your htaccess code that was causing this redirection loop and the other thing can be that you are using header after output

Comment: htaccess code has been reverted and I have created a php file with only this code as content.

Comment: Are you creating output before header. Means any html tag or a blank space too

Comment: exact code as appear in file no blank space before or after first or last character <?php 
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == ""){
    $redirect = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location: $redirect");
} ?>

Comment: Sometimes you won't notice the space.Try to create new file

Comment: Double checked. No spaces at all. Perhaps nothing wrong with the code. A problem with the site being on shared hosting perhaps. Provider doesn't seem to think there is a problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59514/discussion-between-utkarsh-and-user2524219).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
   $prefix = 'https://';
} else {
$prefix = 'http://';
}

$location = $prefix.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Location: $location");
exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: Sorry, same problem as previous answer

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the `header("Location: $redirect");` from the true command of the `if` statement and the script seems to work on all browsers now.

```
<?php 
 if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL'] == '1') {  } else {    $redirect = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");  header("Location: $redirect"); } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
$protocol = ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ) ? 'https' : 'http';
```